# How to translate $split into c# mongodriver equivalent?

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have a project stage like this

```
{
    $project: {
        _id: 1,
        ContractId: 1,
        DomainParts: { $split: ["$Email", "@"] }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to write a C# version of same project stage code, but I'm unable to find the way to do it. Here's what I have, C# driver compiles, but run it returns error

```
.Project
(
    e => new
            {
                _id = 1,
                ContractId = 1,
                DomainParts = new BsonDocument("$split", new BsonArray { "$Email", "@" })
            }
)
```

Comment: i knew it's something simply i missed, lol, i was mixing c# anoymous object with bsondocument, this code works  .Project(new BsonDocument
                    {
                        { "_id", "$_id" },
                        { "ContractId", "$ContractId" },
                        { "DomainParts", new BsonDocument("$split", new BsonArray { "$Email", "@" }) }
                    }
                )

Comment: Hi, good to see you get the answer. Would suggest writing the solution as you mentioned as the answer. So the answer may helps for future readers. You may have a read: [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)